# ASP.NET Core (NET Framework) Teamcity build fails, VS builds properly

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, teamcity

I have an ASP.NET Core project that builds properly with VS but fails with TeamCity.

It is a project that compiles to a library, but TeamCity tries to build it as an executable, and complains about the lack of 'main':

```
CSC error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point
```

The content of the .csproj file are as follow:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup Label="Configuration" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x86</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <OutputTypeEx>library</OutputTypeEx>
    <StartupObject />
    <AssemblyName>Test</AssemblyName>
    <RootNamespace>Test</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Visual studio has no problem building the dll file.

To reproduce:

- Create an ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework) project
- Change the output type to library
- Remove the program.cs / startup.cs files
- Compile with Visual Studio to confirm a library is being built
- Build with Team City and an error will appear

Answer (score 0):

To avoid that error, Please look into this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41156691/asp-net-core-program-does-not-contain-a-static-main-method-suitable-for-an-en) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006744/asp-net-core-web-api-program-does-not-contain-a-static-main-method-suitable-f)

> You should be using the [dotnet core plugin](https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2016/11/teamcity-dotnet-core/) or you can easily
>   configure **dotnet build** command(if dotnet is present in your build
>   servers).

Or you can refer the [MusicStore build.cmd](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/dev/build.cmd) file for reference. This basically downloads and installs the dotnet and all the dependencies and then builds the project.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Regarding the two posts, we don't have a project.json file; this is a classic .csproj file; it is asp.net core but with regular net libraries, it's not the asp.net core with the core libs built from the command line

Comment: the dotnet core plugin will not help because it represent a different build path than the one we're using when developing; as far as VS is concerned, this is a regular csproj; on the TC side, I have cleaned the folders, rebuilt from scratch, etc

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround; in the project file, VS puts this:

```
<OutputTypeEx>library</OutputTypeEx>
```

I need to add one line:

```
<OutputType>Library</OutputType>
<OutputTypeEx>library</OutputTypeEx>
```

So it looks like the build with TeamCity is not handling the *OutputTypeEx* propery but it handles the *OutputType* one.

I still see this as a bug, but at least there is a workaround.